# why is this window not appearing

Tags: callback, window, instantiation, fltk

I want a button's callback method to instantiate a window (with editor) each time the button is clicked, possibly resulting in multiple windows with editors visible simultaneously. For now I would be happy if just one would appear -- it doesn't.

Comments regarding FLTK and C++ programming practice in general are also welcome.

```
#include <FL/Fl.H> 
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Text_Editor.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Text_Buffer.H>

class MainWin : public Fl_Window {

    public:
        MainWin(int w, int h, const char *title);
        ~MainWin();
        Fl_Button* gobtn;
        Fl_Text_Editor* ed; // first editor included with main window
        Fl_Text_Buffer* buf;
    private:
        static void gomthd(Fl_Widget *, void *);        // "go" method
};

class AdditionalWin : public Fl_Window {   // more editors if necessary
    public:
        AdditionalWin(int w, int h, const char *title);
        ~AdditionalWin();
        Fl_Text_Editor *ed;
        Fl_Text_Buffer *buf;
};

int main () {
    MainWin win(105, 405, "main");
    return Fl::run();
}

MainWin::MainWin(int w, int h, const char* title):Fl_Window(w,h,title) {

    gobtn = new Fl_Button(8, 38, 35, 20, "go");
    gobtn->callback(gomthd, this);

    ed = new Fl_Text_Editor(6, 67, 93, 331);
    buf = new Fl_Text_Buffer();
    ed->buffer(buf);

    end();
    resizable(this);
    show();
}

AdditionalWin::AdditionalWin(int w, int h, const char *title):Fl_Window(w, h, title) {

    ed = new Fl_Text_Editor(6, 67, 93, 331);
    buf = new Fl_Text_Buffer();
    ed->buffer(buf);
    end();
    resizable(this);
    show();

}

void MainWin::gomthd(Fl_Widget* o, void* v) {

    AdditionalWin awin(105, 405, "more");
    awin.position(1, 1);
    awin.show();          // ??? nothing appears
}

MainWin::~MainWin(){}
AdditionalWin::~AdditionalWin(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party but still: I think the new window never shows, because awin, being a local variable, gets destroyed as soon as the MainWin::gomthd() function returns.